# Uniform distribution joint density problem

Tags: probability

If you are given a uniformly distributed set of

${(x,y) : y + x <2, 0 < x < 2, 0 < y < 2}$

how can you calculate the joint density of $(X,Y)$ and the marginal density $f_Y(y)$ of $Y$.

My idea is to use symmetry however that seems to be a bit problematic in the approach.

Answer (score 0):

The $(x,y)$ form a right triangle in the plane with area $\frac{1}{2}ab=2$ and because the distribution is uniform you know it has constant height $h$ over this triangle and $0$ elsewhere. The volume under the density is therefore $2h$ and must equal $1$ so $h=\frac{1}{2}$. This gives you the joint density and you can then calculate the marginal density.

Comment: This makes sense, but how would you set the integral?

Answer (score 0):

The constraints you've given specify a triangular region in the first quadrant, with area $2$. The volume under the joint has to be $1$, thus the uniform "height" (i.e. in the $z$-direction) you are looking must be $1/2$. The joint distribution then is $f_{XY}(x,y) = 1/2$, with the constraints you gave. To get the marginal distribution $f_Y(y)$, just integrate the $x$ out of the joint distribution.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense but what is the setup of the integral?> That seems to be where I am running into some trouble.

Comment: actually it seems you just take the integral from - infinity to infinity of 1/2?

Comment: Ah got it now. Integral from 0 to 2 of 1/2xy dx.

Comment: It should go from $0$ to $2-y$ because $2-y$ is your upper bound for $x$. Then the marginal distribution will have a dependency on $y$.

Comment: So 0 to 2-y 1/2xy dx?

Answer (score 0):

Since the distribution is just uniform, let $f_{XY}(x,y)=c$ be the joint density of $X,Y$. Then $c$ must satisfy $\int \int c\,dy\,dx$ over your whole triangular region.

Then $f_Y(y)=\int_0^{2-y}c\,dx$.